# How to draw outside a a CButton

Tags: mfc

I have to draw left (not inside) from a CButton, two little red and green rectangle. I am not sure how to achieve this in the right way. Can I use in DrawItem() the device context from the parent DC to draw it?

```
void CSpecialButton::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct) 
{ ..
  CDC* parentDC = GetParent()->GetDC();
  CRect rcClrRed; 
  .. calculate rcClrRed;
  parentDC->FillSolidRect(rcRed, RGB(255,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Why does the button need to draw beside itself? Why can't the parent draw? Why can't there be a second control on the side? Why can't the button be bigger and draw the rectangles and the button stuff both inside?

Comment: because, there are too many buttons (~20).  That means additional 2 x 20 controls

Comment: How do you want to handle redrawing? Windows will inform the parent if the parent's client area needs to be repainted. Windows does not know that your rogue buttons want to paint outside their area. Your design is broken. See my first comment for better solutions.

Comment: Ok, draw outside is broken! The user don't want the rectangles in the button. So I draw now successfully in DrawItem(..)  a resized button. I  let a left area free for drawing the rectangles. I can colorize the free area with a color what I want, but I want it make transparent too. Draw with a hollow brush does not work here :(